# MySQL password consistency

Tags: mysql

In MySQL 5.1 when I type:

```
select Password('test123');
```

I get password as 41 bytes long. The same, when typed in older MySQL versions, is 16-bytes long. I need to store 16-byte long passwords, so is there any way to specify length (16-bytes) while retrieving/encrypting the password?

Comment: Reference: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/password-hashing.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They changed hashing schemes at one point, but you can still use the old one, it's just named `OLD_PASSWORD` now:

```
SELECT OLD_PASSWORD('test123');
```

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, you can also supply that you want to use old passwords in the connection string

Comment: @Karthick - don't forget to accept the answer once StackOverflow lets you :)